# WordPress Custom Column Content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type for Videos. On the admin edit screen, I have added a custom column called Description to display the value of a custom field.

[Screnshoot of Current Post List Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEjAp.jpg)

I would actually like to display the Description value in the Title column, below the "post title link" and the "quick action links". However, I don't seem to be able to interact with the Title columns as I would expect. I can reorder the Title columns, but cannot print content into it.

```php
// Add Custom Columns to Videos list 
function modify_videos_columns($columns){

    unset($columns['date']);
    unset($columns['author']);
    unset($columns['title']);

    $columns['thumbnail'] = __('Thumbnail');
    $columns['title'] = __('Title');
    $columns['description'] = __('Description');
    $columns['datetime'] = __('Date & Time');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_video_posts_columns', 'modify_videos_columns', 5);

function display_video_custom_columns($column_name, $post_id){
  switch($column_name){

    case "thumbnail":
        print "<a href='" . get_edit_post_link($post_id) . "'><img src='" . get_post_meta($post_id, "video_thumbnail_medium", true) . "' width='150px' /></a>";

    break; 
    case "title":
        print "<p>" . get_field("video_description", $post_id) . "</p>";
    break;  
    case "description":
        print get_field("video_description", $post_id);
    break;
    case 'datetime':
        print date_format(date_create(get_field("video_datetime")), "d/m/y") . ", " . date_format(date_create(get_field("video_datetime")), "g:ia");
        break;
  }
}
add_action('manage_video_posts_custom_column', 'display_video_custom_columns', 5, 2);
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach which has accomplished what I was aiming to do.

Instead of using the default column name "title" (which seems to cause unexpected behaviour), I create a column named "custom_title" and populated it with a title link and description.

I then used the "list_table_primary_column" filter to set the "cstom_title" columns as the default column, which adds the quick edits links into each entry in the column.

```php
// Add Custom Columns to Videos list 
function modify_videos_columns($columns){

    unset($columns['date']);
    unset($columns['author']);
    unset($columns['title']);

    $columns['thumbnail'] = __('Thumbnail');
    $columns['custom_title'] = __('Title');
    $columns['datetime'] = __('Date & Time');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_video_posts_columns', 'modify_videos_columns', 5);

function display_video_custom_columns($column_name, $post_id){
  switch($column_name){

    case "thumbnail":
        print "<a href='" . get_edit_post_link($post_id) . "'><img src='" . get_post_meta($post_id, "video_thumbnail_medium", true) . "' width='150px' /></a>";

    break; 
    case "custom_title":
        print "<strong><a href='" . get_edit_post_link($post_id) . "'>" . get_the_title($post_id) . "</a></strong>";
        print "<p>" . get_field("video_description", $post_id) . "</p>";
    break;  
    case 'datetime':
        print date_format(date_create(get_field("video_datetime")), "d/m/y") . ", " . date_format(date_create(get_field("video_datetime")), "g:ia");
        break;
  }
}
add_action('manage_video_posts_custom_column', 'display_video_custom_columns', 5, 2);

function list_table_primary_column( $default, $screen ) {
    if ( 'edit-video' === $screen ) {
        $default = 'custom_title'; // Set default column
    }
    return $default;
}
add_filter( 'list_table_primary_column', 'list_table_primary_column', 10, 2 );
```